# wrapping long geom_text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue with wrapping long texts in ggplot2. Similar question was asked here [ggplot2 is there an easy way to wrap annotation text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106508/ggplot2-is-there-an-easy-way-to-wrap-annotation-text?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My question is if we have the text like this

```
my_label <- "Some_arbitrarily_larger_text"
```

How can we shrink it using the same method ?

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()+
annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = wrapper(my_label, width = 5))
```

[image]

It seems not working for this case!

Comment: `\n` creates line breaks as you seem to know, so I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am asking about if you have `_` instead of space in the `my_label`. In this case how to wrap the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Unicode zero-width space and substitute all the `_`'s with `_` + it:

```
library(stringi)
library(ggplot2)

my_label <- "Some_arbitrarily_larger_text"
my_label <- stri_replace_all_fixed(my_label, "_", "_\U200B")
```

To the naked eye it's continuous:

```
my_label
## [1] "Some_​arbitrarily_​larger_​text"
```

But, programmatically, it's a word break/wrap opportunity:

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) paste(stri_wrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = wrapper(my_label, width = 5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You can also call `stringr::str_wrap()`, for:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()+
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = stringr::str_wrap(my_label, 5))
```

I don't think either of those will break up a single word, though, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was asking if you don't have space instead `_`. how can we wrap ?