# How to plot frequency of occurrence with condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, frequency

I have a data set with industry names.  when I plot the frequency, it gives me

[image: see picture].

Is there any way to plot the frequency of occurrence but only if the frequency is more than a certain number let's say 10.

I guess what I want is plot the count with a condition.

here is my code:

```r
ggplot(see, aes(x=industry, y=freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", fill="white") + 
    xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Comment: Subset the data before plotting, e.g. `see[see$freq > 10, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter the data before plotting, as below,

```
see %>% filter(freq >= 10) %>%
ggplot(data = .,aes(x=industry, y=freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", fill="white") + 
    xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Comment: it says  Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`

Comment: *break line the xlab*?? do you mean clear representation of labels on x-axis?? if yes, you can do by adding following line: `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`

Comment: Also, as you said, *cool it works*, kindly accept it as answer, so that many others can be benefited as well.

Comment: This will change the text angle to 45 degrees. what I meant is, have the label at the original position but if the text is long, put it on different lines. maybe separate some word with "\n". i am not sure.

Comment: ok, got it. you can definitely use `\n` for the labels. also you can use `stringr::str_wrap` method for the purpose like `+ xlab(str_wrap("lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnglabelllllllllllll  to be be wraapped",width = 10,indent = 5))` Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446259/wrapping-long-geom-text-labels) for details.