# geom_text_repel placing annotations off the chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `geom_text_repel` to annotate some points on a scatter plot. I also need to wrap the text labels so they aren't too long. But they keep being hanging off the graph area and being cut off. I did somehow manage to [get it working before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yghGh.png)but I don't know what I changed to stop it (the plot is saved in my IDE history but I can't get the code back).

I'm using the string wrapping as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446259/wrapping-long-geom-text-labels), and my code is as follows:

```
mobility %>%
  ggplot(aes(access, success, colour=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(mobility, label == 1),
            aes(access, success, label=stringr::str_wrap(university, 3)),
            show.legend = FALSE, box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines"),
            vjust="inward", hjust="inward") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 3), text='none') +
  theme_economist() +
  labs(x='Access rate', y='Success rate', colour='University type', title='Figure 3')
```

Here are the graphs it produces
[with the string wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuGpH.png) and [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyf00.png).

How can I get the labels to wrap, not overlap, and not go off the graph, as in the first image?

###### Data sample:

```
mobility <- structure(list(university = c("Royal Veterinary College", "LSE", 
"Imperial College", "Oxford", "Cambridge", "London South Bank", 
"London Metropolitan", "University of East London", "King's College London Other Russell Group", 
"University of Durham Other Russell Group", "University ofWarwick Other Russell Group", 
"University College London Other Russell Group", "University of Bristol Other Russell Group", 
"QueenMary, University of Lon.. Other Russell Group", "University of Sheffield Other Russell Group"
), group = c("Old Universities (Pre-1992)", "Most Selective Russell", 
"Most Selective Russell", "Most Selective Russell", "Most Selective Russell", 
"Post-1992 (least selective)", "Post-1992 (least selective)", 
"Post-1992 (least selective)", "Other Russell Group", "Other Russell Group", 
"Other Russell Group", "Other Russell Group", "Other Russell Group", 
"Other Russell Group", "Other Russell Group"), access = c(0.013, 
0.046, 0.038, 0.009, 0.01, 0.257, 0.246, 0.295, 0.059, 0.012, 
0.015, 0.043, 0.01, 0.161, 0.016), success = c(0.625, 0.611, 
0.603, 0.59, 0.544, 0.18, 0.164, 0.138, 0.498, 0.489, 0.461, 
0.455, 0.423, 0.422, 0.422), label = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: One option could be to add `coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))` with the `1`s adjusted to taste.

Comment: One challenge is that `ggrepel` uses a random seed, so if you want reproducible results, you'll want to 1) use `set.seed(123)` right before your chain, and 2) keep the output size consistent. You don't specify how you're saving your output, so others will get different output depending on their random seed and their plot window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get better results by:

- removing clipping, to give more room at the edges of the plot
- reducing lineheight and using wider wrapping
- removing the `vjust="inward", hjust = "inward"`. Those determine the horizontal justification as well as the initial placement of the text, and I think in this case (where your labels are all in bunches), it's better to let the algorithm push the labels to the perimeter of each bunch.

(It's also good practice to include in your question the packages that are needed to run the code.)

```
library(ggrepel); library(scales); library(ggthemes)
mobility %>%
  ggplot(aes(access, success, colour=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(data=subset(mobility, label == 1),
                  aes(access, success, label=stringr::str_wrap(university, 8)),
                  show.legend = FALSE, box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines"), 
                  point.padding = unit(0.55, "lines"), 
                  max.time = 3, max.iter = 1E6,
                  lineheight = 0.8,  ylim = c(0,0.8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 3), text='none') +
  theme_economist() +
  labs(x='Access rate', y='Success rate', colour='University type', title='Figure 3')
```

[image]